# How to get the jvm data in the container on the host

Tags: java, docker, jvm

There is such a need to detect whether the jvm code in the container has been maliciously modified. I google some related questions, and We can dynamically monitor jvm through Java Instrumentation. But I failed in the first step, I cannot get the jvm in the container. If it was host jvm, it will be ok.
eg.

Test.java

```java
import com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException;
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineDescriptor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AttachNotSupportedException {
        List<VirtualMachineDescriptor> list = VirtualMachine.list();
        for (VirtualMachineDescriptor virtualMachineDescriptor : list) {
            System.out.println("virtualMachineDescriptor = " + virtualMachineDescriptor);
        }
    }
}
```

I started a springboot project in the background.
javac and run it.

```sh
➜  java javac Main.java
➜  java java Main
virtualMachineDescriptor = sun.tools.attach.BsdAttachProvider@7a81197d: 20819 springboot.jar
virtualMachineDescriptor = sun.tools.attach.BsdAttachProvider@7a81197d: 21492 Main
virtualMachineDescriptor = sun.tools.attach.BsdAttachProvider@7a81197d: 41035
```

It's works. I intend to achieve the same effect in the container

These is my dev env

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04  

JDK: openjdk8 

docker: 
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.6
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        370c289
 Built:             Fri Apr  9 22:46:01 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.6
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       8728dd2
  Built:            Fri Apr  9 22:44:13 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.4
  GitCommit:        05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc93
  GitCommit:        12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

1. Start a web container in the background
   `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 springboot_demo`(springboot_demo that image was built by myself)

```
FROM openjdk:8 

COPY springboot.jar app.jar 

EXPOSE 8080 

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

2. `docker top container_id`
   I get container pid 24820
3. javacode

```
import com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException;
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineDescriptor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AttachNotSupportedException {
        ¦ VirtualMachine vm =  VirtualMachine.attach("24820");
        ¦ System.out.println(vm);

    }
}
```

`javac Main.java && java Main` I got these errors.

```java
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:106)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

**Is it possible to obtain the jvm data in the container from the outside on the same machine?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDK 8 is not namespace aware and thus cannot attach to a JVM process in a different mount namespace (i.e. container).

Attach API has been fixed to work with containers in JDK 10.

Meanwhile there is [jattach](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) project that fixes the problem.
`jattach` allows to connect to any HotSpot JVM in a container (including JDK 8 and even older JDKs) even with no JDK installed on the host (this is a tiny program in pure C). You can use `jattach` in place of Java Attach API to do anything:

- load Java agent;
- get thread dumps and heap dumps;
- invoke `jcmd` command, and more.

Comment: Thanks, I update jdk version. It's works!   I will try to use jattach right away, it is auseful tool that can run without jre environment

Comment: I tried to use JATTACH, but something happened.  The scenario is the same as above, I try to inject different namespace.  ` jattach 15190 -javaagent:/home/skrbug/attack_demo/agent_jdk11.jar` But I got these error `Could not start attach mechanism: No such file or directory`.
And the container's console print some jvm info(Not print my agentmain code that I print all classes ).